# IE space below image?

Tags: html, css

How can I fix this page for Internet Explorer? It seems to add a space below the background images for some reason..

http://orangeguy.biz/profile/

The design is like this:

```
                 ------------------
                 |   TOP IMAGE    |<- base_top.png
                 ------------------
                 |  |          |  |
base_sides.png ->|  | CONTENT  |  |<- base_sides.png
                 |  |          |  |
                 |-----------------
                 |  BOTTOM IMAGE  |<- base_bottom.png
                 ------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because IE has the strange idea that every element should be at least one character high.

If you add `overflow:hidden;` to the #top and #bottom styles, that will keep IE from making the element larger than you have specified.

General tip:
Adding a proper doctype to the page so that it renders in standards compliant mode helps a lot with how IE renders the page.

[W3C: Recommended list of DTDs](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Answer (score 1):

IE has default `font-size` and `line-height`
because that image height little than IE default `font-size` and `line-height`.

set:

```
font-size:0 
line-height:0 
overflow:hidden
```

Comment: Overflow hidden is all that fixed my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly give a `img {margin-bottom:0;}` in your css. IE automatically puts a buffer around images, but it should listen to the rules in the stylesheet.

Comment: They aren't images, but actually background images to certain divs. Should have made that clearer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting margin:0; and padding:0; in the style sheet declaration of * (all) elements at the top. So the problem will not occur again. If I may suggest something else? To align elements in the center I would prefer margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; as suggested by W3.org: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Answer (score 0):

[How can I set CSS only for specific IE browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874290/how-can-i-set-css-only-for-specific-ie-browsers)

```
font-size: 0\9;
line-height: 0\9;
```

works as well.