# How can I set CSS only for specific IE browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a CSS/jQuery Checkbox style script: http://jsfiddle.net/BwaCD/

The problem is, in current browsers in order for the span to float over the input, the input's position must be absolute. But in IE8 & below, the script will not work and therefore I'm left with and absolutely positioned input that is just floating over other elements. I am not asking for the script to work in IE8 & below.

**I want to know how I can use CSS to set a specific style if it is IE8 and below.** I guess jQuery would be acceptable if it's necessary, but I don't think it is. I know this can be done with just CSS & HTML I just don't know how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about that?

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Or that if you don't like those statements

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I just wanna ask though, are these hacks safe at all?

Comment: Hack are bad, always! I suggest using the solution from my first link but if you really must use hacks, I found this website: http://browserhacks.com/ - good to know that these things exist and they do work as desired but you really shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 16):

Conditional comments would work (`<!--[if lte IE 8]><stylesheet><![endif]-->`), but if you want to do it all in the stylesheet, there [is a way](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/):

```
body {  
    color: red; /* all browsers, of course */  
    color: green\9; /* IE only */  
}
```

The important thing here is the "\9", which has to be exactly "\9".  I'm not clear on exactly why this is.

EDIT: The \9 hack isn't enough by itself.  To exclude IE9, you also need the [`:root` hack](http://blog.vervestudios.co/blog/post/2011/05/13/IE9-Only-CSS-Hack.aspx):

```
:root body {
    color: red\9; /* IE9 only */  
}
```

Other browsers besides IE might support `:root`, so combine it with the \9 hack if you're using it to target IE9.

Comment: Looks like the \9 actually targets all versions of IE, not just 8 and below.  http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safe-css-hacks#css-hacks

Comment: \9 works great, and since MS dropped conditional comments starting IE10, this seems the only js-free solution for target IE only. Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer.  not sure what the other answers are doing here

Comment: To target IE 11 you need to use `\0` and for others searching for a LESS solution: `color: e("green\0");`

Answer (score 3):

EDIT (Aug. 28): Note that the following answer is relevant, in practice, only for Internet Explorer, at least versions 8 and earlier. To my knowledge, no mainstream browser now supports conditional comments, not even Internet Explorer 11.

---

You can use Internet Explorer's conditional comments to add a class name to the HTML root tag
for older IE browsers:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can define IE-specific CSS by referencing the appropriate class name, like this:

```
.ie8 body {
   /* Will apply only to IE8 */
}
```

Source: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 2):

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE :

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 5 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 5.5 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters--net-10575

on the example: `color : green\9;`

`\9` didn't work for ie11, but `\0` worked!

Answer (score 1):

I have a useful solution for IE 10 and 11. The script checks for IE and version and then appends .ie10 or .ie11 class to the  tag.

That way you can write specific rules like .ie10 .something {} and they get applied only when the browser is IE 10 or 11.

Check it out, it's useful for graceful degradation, tested on a few commercial sites and not really hacky: http://marxo.me/target-ie-in-css

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way for the grab cursor in Internet Explorer:

```
.grab_cursor {
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: url('../img/cursors/openhand.cur'), url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize; /* standard: note the different path for the .cur file */
    cursor: url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize\9; /* IE 8 and below */
    *cursor: url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize; /* IE 7 and below */
    _cursor: url('img/cursors/openhand.cur'), n-resize; /* IE 6 */
}
```

> In Internet Explorer for Windows up to and including version 8, if a
>   relative URI value is specified in an external style sheet file the
>   base URI is considered to be the URI of the document containing the
>   element and not the URI of the style sheet in which the declaration
>   appears.

**Files tree**:

```
index.html
css/style.css -> here the posted code
img/cursors/openhand.cur
```

**Good references**:

- [One](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer)
- [Two](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)
- [Three](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/12/21/cross-browser-css-cursor-images-in-depth/)
- [Four](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419342/2149425)